# Magento 1.9 : How to add custom link in account sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, navigation

How to add custom link in account sidebar magento 1.x, i can't find it in google, all is for magento 2. please help me a example

Answer (score 1):

The links in that navigation are added via different layout XML files. Here's the code that first defines the block in `layout/customer.xml`. Notice that it also defines some links to add to the menu:

```
    <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>custom_link</name><path>customer/custom_url/</path><label>Custom link</label></action>
    </block>
```

Comment: can you give me a path to it

Comment: app/design/frontend/themename/default/layout/customer.xml

Answer (score 1):

open below your theme file if available otherwise create new file

> app\design\frontend\default\themeXXX\layout\customer.xml

after add below code

```
 <customer_account translate="label">
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink"><name>test checkout</name><path>checkout</path><label>Inchoo Checkout</label></action>
        </reference>
</customer_account>
```

[image]